# bootstrap changing responsive resize point

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap page with this hierachy.

```
>Container-fluid
>  Row
>    Col xs-4
>    Col xs-8
```

I have content in both of these columns.

When I resize the page to make it smaller horizontally, then bootstrap changes the layout automatically. So that the first column is on top of the second. As if an extra row div was added.

I want to change the point in the resize where this happens. So that it happens at a larger screen size, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Just override the css using `!important` or by simply declaring the styling after the bootstrap.css stylesheet overriding your changes. Where you put your refs at in your head take precedence using FIFO.

Comment: What to override?

Comment: In the case of resizing, do a Google search on @media screen(max-width:widthpx)